# Active perl Geo OSM Tiles

Tags: ios, dictionary, openstreetmap, tilemill

I had installed Geo-OSM-Tiles through Active perl.
But the problem is that i dont know in which path it had installed.
Also i need terminal command for downloading tiles through Geo-OSM-Tiles (Active perl).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Geo-OSM-Tiles and all other mass downloading tools are [against the OSM Tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Usage_Policy) and should not be used.

Comment: Thanks tmcw. actually my objective is to create .mbtiles for developing offline map. Is there any other way to create .mbtiles?

Comment: Yes, designing them in TileMil, see the [osm-bright tutorial](http://www.mapbox.com/blog/create-a-custom-map-of-your-city-in-30-minutes-with-tilemill-and-openstreetmap/).

Comment: Ya tmcw. i referred your suggested tutorial and created .mbtiles for chennai(india) etc. But i didn't find OSM data (.pbf) file for pondicherry(india). what can i do for that?